# mongoose query of node api is working in postman but not in cyclic and railway server

Tags: node.js, api, mongoose, postman

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const Pokaranreading=require('../model/pokaranschema');
const moment = require('moment');

router.get('/todaydata',async (req,res)=>{
try {
const startOfToday=moment().startOf('day').toDate();
const endOfToday=moment().endOf('day').toDate();
const Pokreading=await Pokaranreading.find({
**RDate:{
$gte:startOfToday,
$lte:endOfToday
}**
});
res.status(201).json(Pokreading);
} catch (error) {
res.status(404).json(error)
}
})
```

this code is working with postman but not working in cyclic or railway server.

```
RDate:{
$gte:startOfToday,
$lte:endOfToday
}
```

when i commented this piece of code than cyclic/railway is returning data. But when RDate is not commented then cyclic/railway is returning empty array.

Please help`

Comment: This problem has been solve. Would be happy if solution could help someone . I use Luxon instead of moment js. Moment is not working in cyclic/railway sever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toISOString()` for better result.

```js
const startOfToday=moment().startOf('day').toISOString();
const endOfToday=moment().endOf('day').toISOString();
```

I would suggest use `console.log()`or `debug` to see the value of `RDate` in the database

Comment: When using .toISOString() , even postman is showing empty array. Thank you for the reply.